# How can I cut an amr audio file

Tags: sound

I need to cut some portion of an amr file. Is there any software to do so, like mp3 cutter ?. `Audacity` not supporting it.
   [update]
Is it possible in `audacity`, using plugin or something?.   I like a CLI program other than `ffmpeg` as it is not light weight.

Comment: Answer updated. Have a look .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audacity *does* support manipulating amr files provided you are using the FFmpeg plugin:

[http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=FAQ:Installation_and_Plug-Ins#installffmpeg](http://manual.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=FAQ%3aInstallation_and_Plug-Ins#installffmpeg)

The Audacity build that comes with Trust Tahr 14.04 does *not* have this plugin available but a guide has been written to get around this:

Audacity under Trusty Tahr: Building it with FFmpeg
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219907

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

`sudo aptitude install mpgtx`

Then you can cut any file mp3. 
Command : `mptsplit ibputfile.mp3 [00:00:20-00:00:50] -o output.mp3`

There you are cutting a mp3 file from 20sec to 50sec.

To cut from .amr file

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -t 30 -acodec copy -i inputfile.amr outputfile.amr
```

There inputfile.amr should be your input file and output.amr should be your output file. 30 stands for a slice 30 sec from the input file from starting.

This could be used for slicing the both .amr and .mp3 files.

Comment: Is .amr supported?

Answer (score 2):

If u still can't cut or edit amr file, please convert ur amr files to mp3 then open and edit using audacity.
This is the step.
Convert ur amr to mp3 with this cmd from terminal, be sure that u have install ffmpeg.

ffmpeg -i nameyourfiless.amr -ab 128k yourfile.mp3

If u hate using terminal, just install this software. download in here [right click save] http://www.miksoft.net/products/mmc_1.7.7_i386.deb

[image]

open mobile media converter (mmc) .convert ur amr to mp3 .

edit as u want this mp3 using audacity.

After finish with ur job you can convert again from mp3 tom amr with this tool mobile media converter. download in here http://www.miksoft.net/products/mmc_1.7.7_i386.deb

convert to amr and that's that!